# Tridion Re-Index tool cannot be executed

Tags: 2011

when trying to run the TcmReIndex.exe tool, we get an error message like:

**Account ##acountname## has no permission to access the protected configuration section 'database'. Contact your system administrator**

Some extra information regarding the account used:

- account is set as 'admin' in Tridion
- account is not the default MTSUser
- the setup of the Tridion software was not done by this user

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This configuration section is encrypted and the user you are using does not have access. You can fix this by using.

```
aspnet_regiis -pa "TridionRsaKeyContainer" "<domain>\<account>"
```

See the manual section [Granting users access to encryption functionality](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_215FCD336DE34DD5AD342951F6AB3683) (login required)

Comment: this fixed the issue indeed; it was included in our roll-out plan, but after a check-up, it was executed for the wrong users..Thx!